# Controllers in general with laravel

Tags: php, controllers, laravel-5.6

Imagine I have this route

```
Route::get('/services/{service}', 'ServiceController@show');
```

when I do

```
public function show($s)
{
  $service = Services::findOrFail($s)
}
```

where `$s` is a string that might be something like "clean" that has the id 1 for example.

It's better to make the route I have or find it for the ID like

```
Route::get('/services/{id}', 'ServiceController@show');

public function show($id)
{
  $service = Services::findOrFail($id)
}
```

It doesn't matter the function I use, the important thing here if it is valid to search by name rather than id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when `$s` is sting you must be make sure for your databse table correspond column is `unique`. For avoid that you can make your route

```
Route::get('/services/{id}/{service}', 'ServiceController@show');

public function show($id, $service)
{
  $service = Services::where(['id' => $id, 'service' => $service])->first()
}
```